# How to measure employee ownership, team spirit, and collaborative nature?

Tags: io-psychology

We are trying to develop metrics that measure levels of ownership, team spirit and collaboration within our group. The assumption is that these three traits are key to being productive employees. Once these measures are developed, we will test whether these measures are predictive of project outcome, ie, do teams with high scores on the ownership/teamwork/collaboration scales typically more productive (as measured by another set of measures).

**How can you measure an employees level of ownership, team spirit and collaborative nature?**

Comment: Hi @Anjan, welcome at CogSci. Could you please provide a little bit more context to your question. Some explanation about the phenomenon that you want to measure and why you want to measure it, for example. That may greatly increase the likelihood that your question will be answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Robin. Thanks. We are trying to develop metrics that measure levels of ownership, team spirit and collaboration within our group. The assumption is that these three traits are key to being productive employees. Once these measures are developed, we will test whether these measures are predictive of project outcome, ie, do teams with high scores on the ownership/teamwork/collaboration scales typically more productive (as measured by another set of measures). Hope this clarifies my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about a range of concepts.
You could look into measures related to:

- Organisational citizenship behaviour: This tends to look at good discretionary behaviors such as collaboration, helping out colleagues, and so on.
- Engagement and affective commitment: Both these constructs are closely related to motivation and alignment with the organisation (e.g., ownership).

Just do a search on google scholar for articles on these topics and look at the methods sections.

There are a range of popular measures that could readily be applied as self-report instruments. Alternatively, you could get peers or supervisors to rate employees.

A few suggestions:

- Lee and Allen's (2002) Organizational Citizenship Behavior Scale.
- [Utrecht engagement scale](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8qbn06vnPAhWMnpQKHRLSAJwQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wilmarschaufeli.nl%2Fpublications%2FSchaufeli%2F251.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEXGZlXkHp_i7tl0s4yn6BsHmk80A&sig2=aQdS3ZrWYUou5q06w23usQ)